# printf in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I have to work with eclipse in C. I wrote a simple program, but I have a problem with a `printf` command which doesn't work properly. Any idea? 
Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void change(double *x, double *y)
{
 double help = *x;
  *x = *y;
 *y = help;
 return;
}

int main()
{
double x=0, y=0;

printf("please give a value to a  \n ");
scanf("%f",&x);
printf("please give a value to b  \n");
scanf("%f",&y);

printf("x=%.2f\t y=%.2f\n",x,y);
printf("will give \n");
change(&x,&y);
printf("x=%.2f\t y=%.2f\n",x,y);
return 0;
}
```

So the problem is that I dont't get this first `printf`.

Comment: What does getting a printf mean?

Comment: Change your `double`s to `float`s or use `%lf`. `%f` is only for `float`; `%lf` is only for `double`.

Comment: There is an ugly difference between scanf and printf when using double: Use `%lf` in scanf. And `%f` in printf.

Comment: Addition to @nneonneo's comment and @KingsIndian's answer: `%f` is used for a `double` in `printf`, since when you pass a `float` to `printf` it'll be promoted to `double`. Since your passing an address to `scanf`, you must distinguish between a `float*` and `double*` because they're obviously two different things.

Comment: Sure, but it's best not to rely on implicit promotions like that. Keep the symmetry: `%lf` for `double`, `%f` for `float`.

Comment: You're not relying on anything, that's how the language works and that's how it's described in the `printf` man pages.

Comment: the %lf or %f dowsn't explain why the first printf is not dispayed on the consol sure some data will be lost but the first printf doesn't need or use them ? and it works prefectly with Visual Studio !! 
thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your values are `double` for which you have to use `%lf`. Buut you are using `%f` which invokes undefined behaviour.

Change `%f` to `%lf` in your scanfs and prints.

Comment: when I try to debug the programm scanf oder %lf %f are not a problem the queustion is why the first printf doesn't work even there's no %lf or %f  ??? and the programm is correct my problem is why eclipse doesn't run it properly ? 
thanks again for your help

Comment: I don't see anything related VS asked in your question/comments. Passing incorrect format specifier to printf is undefined, so anything can happen.

Comment: It's undefinied behaviour so can work on some platforms/compilers but don't need to. Eclipse itself is not a compiler (either VS) but in most cases it use GCC.

Comment: yes I'm useGCC it work after all but only if I give some number is the console and than the last value of x and y is stay the same, means x = 0 and y = 0

Comment: here is an other example  :

    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
 int i =0 , j = 0;
 printf("give the value for i ");
 scanf("%d", &i);
 print("give the value for j");
 scanf("%d", &j);
 printf(" i value is %d and j value is %d", i , j);
 return 0;
    }

Comment: This is really simple. All you have to do is: change all `%f` with `%lf`. The other code you in the comment should work as well.

Comment: No it isn't : 
please see why i get : 
[link1](http://imgur.com/ZrqLM,k5LHv#0)
[link2](http://imgur.com/ZrqLM,k5LHv#1)

Comment: got it I have to use fflush(stdout) after  printf and it work so it wasn't this stuff of %lf.
thanks for your help anyway